# conflict in ng-model and name property in checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, checkbox

I have code like this ...

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked3" ng-init="checked3=true" name="checkBoxRangeVal" />
<div class="add-required-validation" ng-show="checked3">
</div>
```

In here what I do is from the document load I set the `checkbox` value to true.
Using angular I show and hide the `div` and catch the `checkbox` value using checkbox's name property.

but when the form begin it show the `div` but `checkbox` not have a checked.
( that means check box not show the tick)

How I solve this??

Or can someone suggest me a alternative way to do this??

Comment: for starters you should always use objects in `ng-model` . You could very well have a child scope problem here because using primitives breaks 2 way binding in a child scope. Show more of the html. Also should not use `ng-init` here...should set the scope  model instead

Comment: Your code works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/55r3qd1r/

Comment: if there conflict in ng-model and name property ??

Comment: @charlietfl -- can you explain your point bit more please or give me something to follow

Comment: this 3 minute video is simplest explanation I know  https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-the-dot